# How do I avoid redirect to custom IdP logout endpoint when using NextJS Auth0?

Tags: next.js, next.js13, auth0

I am using the [`nextjs-auth0`](https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0) plugin to implement authentication in a NextJS application, where the OIDC IdP I am using is a custom IdP and not Auth0. As such, the logout endpoint on that custom IdP is not enabled.

I am using the API route handler and my `/app/api/auth/[auth0]/route.js` is currently:

```
import { handleAuth } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';

export const GET = handleAuth();
```

I have a logout link that calls `/app/api/auth/[auth0]/route.js` and results in a redirect to my IdP's logout URL which is not enabled, resulting in an error.  I want to perform a logout that will clear my session cache and cookies but that will not redirect away from the site.

How do I do override this `handleAuth()` implementation to do this please?

Answer (score 0):

Create a file at `/app/api/auth/logout/route.ts` and expose your custom logout handler there.

Since `logout` is more specific than `[auth0]`, it takes precedence.